# Javascript Opacity Slider Not Working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I needed a component to change the color of an image with a slider. To do this, I modified Javascript code to change the opacity of a different colored image on top of the original image as the slider moved. I also added a dimming function that dims the image using opacity and a black div.

It works perfect in Chrome and Firefox. I can't for the life of me figure out how to get it to work in Internet Explorer. I'm new to Javascript so it may be obvious, but can someone help?!?

**HTML**

```
<img src="images/warm-1170.jpg" id="warm">
<img src="images/cool-1170.jpg" id="cool">
<div class="blackBoxDimmer" id="dimmer"></div>
<div id="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="0" max=".99" step=".01" value=".5" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>
<p id="x1">2700K</p>
<p id="x2">5000K</p>
<h4 id="sliderTitleColor">Color Adjustment</h4>
<div id="dimAdjustSlider">
<div id="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="0" max=".5" step=".01" value="0" class="slider" id="myRangeDim">
</div>
</div>
<p id="y1">5%</p>
<p id="y2">100%</p>
<h4 id="sliderTitleDim">Dimming Function</h4>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family: "arial", serif;
}
.container {
    width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
.blackBoxDimmer {
    display: block;
    width: 1170px; /* !!!Adjust this to match image width */
    height: 671px; /* !!!Adjust this to match image height */
    margin-top: -675px;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: black;
}
#warm {
    position: absolute;
}
#cool {
    opacity: .5;
}
input[type=range] {
  /*removes default webkit styles*/
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /*fix for FF unable to apply focus style bug */
  border: 1px solid white;
  /*required for proper track sizing in FF*/
  width: 800px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 800px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #ddd;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #82c341;
  margin-top: -4px;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #ccc;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 800px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #ddd;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  border: none;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #82c341;
}
/*hide the outline behind the border*/

input[type=range]:-moz-focusring {
  outline: 1px solid white;
  outline-offset: -1px;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 800px;
  height: 5px;
  /*remove bg colour from the track, we'll use ms-fill-lower and ms-fill-upper instead */
  background: transparent;
  /*leave room for the larger thumb to overflow with a transparent border */
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 6px 0;
  /*remove default tick marks*/
  color: transparent;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #777;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  border: none;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #82c341;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #888;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #ccc;
}
#slidecontainer {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 180px;
}
#dimAdjustSlider {
    display: inline-block;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    margin-left: 180px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#y1 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    margin: 25px 0 0 -972px;
}
#y2 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    margin: 25px 0 0 -233px;
}
#sliderTitleDim {
    margin-top: -70px;
    margin-left: 513px;
    margin-bottom: 75px;
}
.dimmingBox {
    display: block;
}
#x1 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    margin-left: 190px;
    margin-right: 705px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#x2 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px !important;
}

#sliderTitleColor {
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
    margin-left: 513px;
}
.textAlignLeft {
    text-align: left !important;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
        var output = .5;
        var imageTrans = document.getElementById("cool");
        output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value

        // Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
        slider.oninput = function() {
            output.innerHTML = this.value;
            imageTrans.style.opacity = slider.value;
        }

        var sliderDim = document.getElementById("myRangeDim");
        var outputDim = 0;
        var imageTransDim = document.getElementById("dimmer");
        outputDim.innerHTML = sliderDim.value; // Display the default slider value

        // Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
        sliderDim.oninput = function() {
            outputDim.innerHTML = this.value;
            imageTransDim.style.opacity = sliderDim.value;
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to change the event you are attaching your javascript function to - from `oninput` to `onchange` or `onmousemove` for old IE users.

Comment: Looks like that did it. I figured it would be a small thing like that. Thanks zgood!